# Static Lazy Initializer

Tags: java, lazy-initialization

I have a class that configures a server. The server object is static and is lazy initialised. The issue is, some of the config for the server comes from non-static member variables of the containing class. Obviously, the non-static members cannot be accessed. Is there a way around this, that I can configure my server using non-static variables? The server must remain static.

```
public class ClassA {

private static MyServer myServer;
private int a;
private int b;

public ClassA(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public static MyServer getMyServer() {

    if(myServer == null) {
        myServer = configureServer();
    }

    return myServer;
}

private static MyServer configureServer() {
    MyServer myServer = new MyServer();
    myServer.setaPlusB(a + b);

    return myServer;
}
```

}

```
public class MyServer {

    private int aPlusB;

    public void setaPlusB(int aPlusB) {
        this.aPlusB = aPlusB;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen? Your questions is strange and abstract. Which non-static variables do you want to use to configure your server? Where should they come from? Of course you can pass non-static variables as parameters to the `getMyServer` method. But if you don't want that - where should they come from?

Comment: The only way would be to use an instance of ClassA as parameter when you call the getMyServer function. Btw the "static lazy getter" is calles singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understood it as something like below;

```
public class Server {

   private class ServerImpl {

       private int ab;

       public ServerImpl() {

           ab = Server.a + Server.b;
       }
   }

   private static int a;
   private static int b;
   private static ServerImpl s;

   static {

      a = 10;
      b = 10;
   }

   public static ServerImpl getServer(int newA, int newB) {

       a = newA;
       b = newB;
       return getServer();
   }

   public static ServerImpl getServer() {

       if (s == null) {
          s = new ServerImpl();
       }
       return s;
   }
}
```